# Restore Production pgbackup to Development database on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have a very basic application deployed on Heroku that has gathered data over the last week and a half. I now want to do some more development on the site and would like to copy the data from my production application database across to the database being used for my development.

I added pgbackups using the following command:

```
heroku addons:add pgbackups
```

I then captured the production database using

```
heroku pgbackups:capture
```

When I run `heroku pgbackups` I can see the following:

```
ID    Backup Time                Status                                Size    Database                                                                                                                                           
----  -------------------------  ------------------------------------  ------  ---------     ---------------------------------                                                                                                         
b001  2014/06/19 13:31.08 +0000  Finished @ 2014/06/19 13:31.10 +0000  27.7KB  HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_AMBER_URL (DATABASE_URL)
```

I'm now tring to use the following command to restore this backup to my development database  on Heroku (orange)

```
heroku pgbackups:restore HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_ORANGE b001
```

but I'm getting the following message:

```
 !    Unknown database: HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_563f103f. Valid options are: DATABASE_URL, HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_AMBER_URL
```

Is it possible to do what I want and if so how do I do it? I've been trying to find an answer the last couple of hours but am getting confused with the concept of development-staging-production. Everything I'm finding refers to copying a db from production to staging but as far as I can see I'm trying to copy from production to development. Thanks for looking

Comment: Been at this all day and haven't figured it out yet. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the databases in two separate apps, i.e. a development app and a production app? If so, try using the pgbackups:transfer command to transfer data between applications. Docs available [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrade-heroku-postgres-with-pgbackups#transfering-databases-between-heroku-applications).

Basically try:

```
heroku pgbackups:transfer HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_AMBER_URL <development app name>::HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_ORANGE -a <production app name>
```

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. I gues I'll have to try set up a staging environment. Thanks anyway Alex

Comment: For anyone who happens upon this, I used the excellent tutorial here (http://www.mattboldt.com/heroku-staging-production-environments/) to set up separate staging and production environments (both working off the same database)

Comment: Alex's answer above is correct. I hadn't added pgbackups to my development app but once I done that I was able to copy the database using the command he gives above. Thanks Alex